# Generating 2D Triangle and 3D pyramid from list of indices.

Tags: linear-algebra

Given

- n = max value in set (for triangle, that would be $\frac{b^2 + b}{2}$) If someone could tell me what formula I would need to determine the size of the pyramid (without using $\sum_{}$, that would also be very helpful.)
- i = Set of numbers from 0 to n
- b = length of base of triangle/pyramid

How would I use the numbers' value to generate a list of points the create a triangle or pyramid?

I know to make a grid, I could do:

$$point.x = i\bmod b$$
$$point.y = \lfloor\frac{i}{b}\rfloor$$

So I think for the x value at least, I would probably still mod i by some function of i that would return the size of the given row it is on:

$$point.x = i\bmod f(i) - \frac{f(i)}{2}$$

I subtract $\frac{f(i)}{2}$ to keep the rows centered.

Then similarly the y value, would need to increase by 1 I think the same way

$$point.y = \lfloor\frac{i}{f(i)}\rfloor$$

Example:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Would turn into:
    5
  3   4
0   1   2
Where the coords would equal:
            (1,2)
    (0.5, 1),    (1.5, 1)
(0, 0)      (1, 0)      (2, 0)
```

Then for pyramids I assume I would need similar math.
For a 3D grid I know I would use:
$$point.x = i\bmod b$$
$$point.y = \lfloor\frac{i}{b^2}\rfloor$$
$$point.z = \lfloor\frac{i}{b}\rfloor$$

I'm not sure if I could reuse the f(i) function used for the triangle to determine :
$$point.x = i\bmod f(i) - \frac{f(i)}{2}$$
$$point.y = \lfloor\frac{i}{f(i)^2}\rfloor$$
$$point.z = \lfloor\frac{i}{f(i)} - \frac{f(i)}{2}\rfloor$$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. 
Please take a look at 
[this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) 
to see how to format math on this site.

Comment: Ah thanks. That's a lot better.